# Array/list of strings as a model

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I'm looking for a way to convert such a response to a model (a list of strings as a model?):

```
{
    "success": true,
    "msg": null,
    "data": [
        "string 1",
        "string 2",
        "string 3",
        "string 4"
    ],
    "errors": null
}
```

Normally, I would use a normal store, but what to use as a model?

```
Ext.define('myStoreName', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Store', 
    model : ???, //What to use in here, or which store to extend?
    proxy : {
        type : 'betterrest',
        url : 'myUrl',
        headers : {
            'Accept' : 'application/json'
        },
        reader : {
            type : 'json',
            root : 'data',
            totalProperty : 'total',
            successProperty : 'success'
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Ext.data.ArrayStore`](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.data.ArrayStore):

> Small helper class to make creating Ext.data.Stores from Array data easier. An ArrayStore will be automatically configured with a Ext.data.reader.Array.